Pandas groupby operation causes huge memory allocation with relatively small input dataframe, when setting observed=False
I encountered a memory issue with pandas groupby operation when setting observed=False. My input dataframe is relatively small (79,860 rows × 790 columns), but the operation tried to allocate over 40GB of memory.
Here's a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the dramatic difference between observed=True and observed=False:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(42)
n_rows = 79860
n_cols = 790

# Create sample data
data = {
    'chrom': ['chr1'] * n_rows,
    'start': range(n_rows),
    'end': range(1, n_rows + 1)
}

# Add sample columns with random values
for i in range(n_cols - 3): 
    data[f'sample_{i}'] = np.random.random(n_rows)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Melt the dataframe
df_melted = pd.melt(df, 
                    id_vars=["chrom","start","end"],
                    var_name="SampleId",
                    value_name="beta")

# Create beta groups
bins = [0, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0]
labels = ["UU", "MU", "MM"]
df_melted['beta_group'] = pd.cut(df_melted['beta'], 
                                bins=bins, 
                                labels=labels, 
                                right=True, 
                                include_lowest=True)

# Test with observed=True (fast, memory efficient)
start = time.time()
result = df_melted.groupby(
    ['chrom','start','end','beta_group'],
    observed=True
).size().reset_index(name='count')
end = time.time()
print(f"Time with observed=True: {(end-start) * 1000:.2f} ms")

# Test with observed=False (very slow, memory intensive)
start = time.time()
result = df_melted.groupby(
    ['chrom','start','end','beta_group'],
    observed=False
).size().reset_index(name='count')
end = time.time()
print(f"Time with observed=False: {(end-start) * 1000:.2f} ms")

Python version: 3.13
Pandas version: pandas>=2.2.3
With observed=True: Takes ~10 seconds, memory usage is reasonable;
With observed=False: Takes much longer, tries to allocate more than 40GB memory
Why does setting observed=False cause such a dramatic increase in memory usage?
Is this expected behavior for pandas?

There is likely already an answer for this; observed false returns a Cartesian of the inputs, compared to observed true, which returns only the inputs in the dataframe. Your grouping column is a categorical. You can also have a look at the pandas docs for more info
